# Extending Liferay 7 default theme

Tags: liferay-theme, liferay-7

I am looking to change just a few attributes for the default Liferay 7 theme:

- Left Justify the navbar
- Hide the Search control in the navbar
- Allow a second level to each menu

It seems this is best done using a Themelet?  Curious if someone could point me to an existing implementation I could use as a starting point for such a customization.

Thanks,
Randy

Answer (score 0):

To allow a seconde level or ( Child of Child) you should add another loop inside each element. Here is the **FreeMarker** code to put into **navigation.ftl**, and you can add you CSS on it.

```html
<nav id="navigation" role="navigation">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <ul class="nav1">
 
   <#list nav_items as nav_item>
   <li><a href="${nav_item.getURL()}">${nav_item.getName()}</a>
      
     <#if nav_item.hasChildren()>
     <div class="fulldrop">
     
     <#list nav_item.getChildren() as nav_child>
     
     <div class="col-xs-4">
      <#assign  navchild_name = nav_child.getName() />
       
        <h3>${nav_child.getName()}</h3>
        
        <br> 
         <#if nav_child.hasChildren()>
          
          <ul>
           <#list  nav_child.getChildren() as nav_child>
           <li><a href="${nav_child.getURL()}">${nav_child.getName()}</a></li>
           </#list>
          </ul>
          
          </#if>  
     </div>   
      
      </#list>
      </div>
     </#if>
   </li>
   </#list>
     </ul>
     </div>
     
</div>

</nav>
```